# Is everything in later episodes of Adventure Time just a dream?

Tags: adventure-time

In the end of the episode "Evicted!", we see Finn and Jake hypnotized by King Worm, and it ends on that note without any real resolution. Fast forward a couple seasons, and we have "King Worm", where Finn and Jake finally break out of the hypnotism that King Worm had put them under.

So that being said, was everything from "Evicted!" through "King Worm" merely just a dream?

Comment: When I get off this blasted train, I will endeavor to answer this.

Comment: I believe so. I was also thinking the same thing. My mind has been blown.

Comment: Right the reason I don't remember 'King worm' is that I've not seen, attempting to rectify that now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

#### At least, it's *very* unlikely.

In 'King Worm' Fin uses his fears to break the dream world. One of his fears is of the ocean, another of the Lich King. Since 'Evicted' he has faced both of those fears, both with him acting very scared. If King Worm could suppress those fears previously then he could do so now.

The only supporting evidence I can find outside of those two episodes (i.e. not in King Worm or Evicted) is that we see fears flying out of Finns belly button, in 'Ocean of Fear', including the fear feaster. It's *possible* that in Ocean of Fear, the fear feaster is eating the fears so they don't destroy the dream world. But that's a pretty sketchy argument.

It should pretty clear if they have been dreaming in the next few episodes, by other's memories.

As Enricau [mentions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22249/3804), the dreams feature Flame Princess, who isn't introduced until after 'Evicted', and there are several other additions that cannot be explained.

Further to this, characters return in later episodes that would require re-introducing had they just been Dream Figments.

Comment: Valid points, but I'm still thinking that he's been dreaming since the original hypnotism took place, simply because it took the shock of all those fears at once to break the dream world. In each episode so far, Finn has faced each of the fears on their own, which could've been more than manageable for King Worm.

Comment: @TerranceShaw I kind of feel that's too cheap a trick to pull, but I think you might be right. See my last edit.

Answer (score 9):

The Lich, Flame Princess, Fear Feaster, and the Ghost Lady are from episodes later than Evicted, so King Worm can't be a direct continuation. Also, aside from the contrast between the detailed reality of the episodes between Evicted and King Worm compared to the random, illogical dream of King Worm, the Worm king is not smart enough to have recreated reality so finely, as shown when he indirectly told Finn the key to escaping the dream, to manifest his fears. You can consider the two episodes a long joke to make us think things may have been a dream, but don't take it too seriously.

Comment: True enough, though recent episodes seem to have changed things up a bit in the Land of Ooo.

Answer (score 2):

I was mindblown too but I think it's true. I have to consider **if** this is the episode right after ''Evicted''! How can flame princess be in this episode? She was introduced after ''Evicted''.

Comment: This is a great point!

Comment: She can be there because throughout all the episodes up to "King Worm", Finn would still be adventuring through the dream world manifested by the King Worm.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason I believe that this was all just a dream is that I paused the scene where the dreaming started and stopped and they match each other exactly. Only the little worms are gone when the dreams ends and Finn and Jake come back to reality, I agree that we will just have to wait for further evidence on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it all was a dream then flame princess wuldnt be Finns girlfriend, but she still is to this very point. So it cannot be a dream.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it just possible that the dream episode is a second installment of the the episode ending with the worm king. A sort of cross season continuation. Its also worth noting that the little worms are seen throughout the series from the first episode through to the dream episode.